# how to avoid button click event when enter the textbox on textchanged event in asp .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

I have a textbox that takes a month as a value, when this is changed the text_changed event fires which includes the  vaildtextbasemonth() method

```
 private void vaildtextbasemonth()
{
  this_month = DateTime.Now.Month;
  current_year = DateTime.Now.Year;
  this_year = Convert.ToInt32(TxtBase.Text);
  current_month = DateTime.Now.Month;
  if (swyearerror != 0)
  {
   swyearerror = 0;
   TxtBase.Focus();
   }
   else if (Information.IsNumeric(TxtBase1.Text))
   {
   base_month = Convert.ToInt32(TxtBase1.Text);

  if (base_month > this_month & current_year == this_year)
   {
   string message = "Base month may not be in future";
   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
   sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
   sb.Append("alert('");
   sb.Append(message);
   sb.Append("')};");
   sb.Append("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
  (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    TxtBase1.Focus();
  }
  else
   {
   if (base_month < 1 | base_month > 12)
   {
    string message = "Month must be numeric";
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
    sb.Append("alert('");
    sb.Append(message);
    sb.Append("')};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
    (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
     TxtBase1.Focus();
}
  else
     {
      if (base_month != current_month)
     {
      current_month = base_month;
      Calc_Rotation();
      Calc_Best_Before();
     }
      //txtBestBefore.SetFocus
   }
 }
}
  else
{
   string message = "Month must be numeric";
   System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
   sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
   sb.Append("alert('");
   sb.Append(message);
   sb.Append("')};");
   sb.Append("</script>");
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
   (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
   TxtBase1.Focus();
  }

}
```

this the .aspx of the print button

```
 <asp:Button ID="Print" runat="server" 
OnClick="Print_Click1" Text="Print" />
```

this is the code for the print button, It is annoying because according to my program flow user changes the month and then the new rotation code and best before date get populated then the user enters the quantity to print then clicks the print button but here since it fires print event automatically when the user changes the text it throws an error that states the qty is empty which is checked on print_click event.

```
 protected void Print_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtItem.Text) 
    && String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtQty.Text))
      {
     string message = "Please Enter an Item 
        and Qty Before Clicking the Print Button";
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new 
     System.Text.StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
     sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
     sb.Append("alert('");
     sb.Append(message);
     sb.Append("')};");
     sb.Append("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
 (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
   }
     else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtQty.Text))
   {
  string message = "Please Enter an Qty Before
            Clicking the Print Button";
           System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new 
     System.Text.StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
     sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
     sb.Append("alert('");
     sb.Append(message);
     sb.Append("')};");
     sb.Append("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
 (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
    }
   else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtItem.Text))
   {
    string message = "Please Enter an Item 
         Before Clicking the Print Button";
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new 
     System.Text.StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
     sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
     sb.Append("alert('");
     sb.Append(message);
     sb.Append("')};");
     sb.Append("</script>");
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
 (this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());            }
   else
   {
    Printlabels();
   }
   }
```

so right after this event the print button click event get fired automatically, I checked the code I don't see a call for the click button anywhere, I am not sure why it is treating another method as part of valid base item method.

**Any help is seriously appreciated!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if the method Print_Click1 isn't defined as handle for another event in your HTML.

Comment: how can I do that, as far as I can see it isn't defined as handle for any other event